# How to force number to get to the next integer with HTML JS?

Tags: javascript, html, long-integer

**The project**
I'd like to display 9 images (3x3) on a page with dynamic src and change the images by using buttons (Next or previous). Every pictures have 5 tags (ex: sky, new-york, cooking,...) and by chosing a tag every pictures related to this tag will appear.

**My problem**
I don't seems to find the function to force js to go to the next integer as soon as the result of a calcul have decimals so I can't determine the number of pages.

**Example of what I'd like to do**
I want to see all the pictures related to food by clicking on the tag.

```
numberOfPictures = 9 
numberOfPages = numberOfPictures/9    //number of pages = 1 so I'll display one page
```

I want to see all the pictures related to traveling by clicking on the tag.

```
numberOfPictures = 10 
numberOfPages = numberOfPictures/9    //number of pages = 1,111111 so I'll display 2 pages
```

For the moment I only found a way to get an integer but if the decimals are lower than 5 it get to the lowest integer witch "Hide" some pictures.

Thanks for your time!-Vincent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) function:

```js
const numOfPics = 10

console.log(Math.ceil(numOfPics/9))
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's what I needed!